# Testing if a function is called inside another function Jest

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs, moxios

I am writing a Redux action to fulfill a unit test a but am having trouble with the mocked function call inside the test. I believe I have mocked `completeRegistration` correctly, by importing the module it is declared in and then mocking the function from the module reference, but Jest says the function doesn't get called despite the console log statement confirming that the `verified.data.success` condition is `true`.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks

auth.js

```
export const verifyEmail = ({
    originalCode,
    confirmCode,
    token
}) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            originalCode,
            confirmCode,
            registering: true
        });
        const verified = await axios.post("/api/email/verify", body, config);
        if (verified.data.success) {
            console.log("Success!") // logs "Success!"
            completeRegistration(token); // test is to find out if this function gets called
        } else {
            return { msg: "Code did not match, please try again" };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAILED
        });
    }
};
```

auth.test.js

```
import * as auth from "../../actions/auth";

const originalCompleteReg = auth.completeRegistration;

describe("verifyEmail action", () => {
    let verifyData;
    beforeEach(() => {
        verifyData = {
            originalCode: "1234546",
            confirmCode: "1234546",
            token: "87618g1u8ojb98k3jb12i3kwdbcjwvbbi92ueg29eubv" // fake data :p
        };
        auth.completeRegistration = jest.fn(() => auth.completeRegistration);
        moxios.install();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        auth.completeRegistration = originalCompleteReg;
        moxios.uninstall();
    });

    it("calls completeRegistration function if successful", async () => {
        moxios.wait(() => {
            const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
            request.respondWith({
                status: 200,
                response: { success: true }
            });
        });

        const store = mockStore({ payload: {} });

        await store.dispatch(auth.verifyEmail(verifyData));
        expect(auth.completeRegistration).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

Output

```
verifyEmail action › calls completeRegistration function if successful

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

Comment: Hi @andy, in your test I don't see where `verifyEmail` is imported from. Is in the same file where `completeRegistration` method is placed? Can you update your question to include the import of `verifyEmail` in your test?

Comment: There was a typo, thanks for picking it up. So `import * as auth from "../../actions/auth";` brings in `verifyEmail` and it's called using `auth.verifyEmail`

Comment: Your problem is already solved then?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that was a typo I made as I was posting the question. The code in the question is now the same as the code in my editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not mocking the internal value of `completeRegistration` used by `verifyEmail` within the `auth` module, but the exported value.

When you import a module you get an object with references to the module's functions. If you overwrite a value in the required module, your own reference is overwritten, but the implementation keeps the original reference.

So, in your case, if you call `auth.completeRegistration` in your test file you will call the mocked version. But when calling `auth.verifyEmail` (which internally calls `completeRegistration`), the `completeRegistration` it references is not your overwritten version.

I think you should not be testing that your `completeRegistration` method is being called (after all, that's an implementation detail). Instead, you should check that your method behaves as expected (i.e. the behaviour `completeRegistration` has, be it a redirection to another page, perform an additional request, save a cookie, etc). So, you would be mocking the API that is being used in `completeRegistration` but not the method itself.

That being said, if you want to check that `completeRegistration` is being called you still have a couple of options.

## **Use babel [rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) plugin**

You'll have to install the plugin and add it to your babel configuration. Once you have done so, your test would look like:

```
import AuthModule from '../../actions/auth';
import * as auth from '../../actions/auth';

describe('verifyEmail action', () => {
    let verifyData;

    beforeEach(() => {
        verifyData = {
            originalCode: '1234546',
            confirmCode: '1234546',
            token: '87618g1u8ojb98k3jb12i3kwdbcjwvbbi92ueg29eubv'
        };
        moxios.install();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        moxios.uninstall();
    });

    it('calls completeRegistration function if successful', async () => {
        moxios.wait(() => {
            const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
            request.respondWith({
                status: 200,
                response: { success: true }
            });
        });

        const mockFn = jest.fn();
        AuthModule.__Rewire__('completeRegistration', mockFn);

        const store = mockStore({ payload: {} });

        await store.dispatch(auth.verifyEmail(verifyData));
        expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        AuthModule.__ResetDependency__('completeRegistration');
    });
});
```

## **Separate the functions in different files**

You can create a separate module for `completeRegistration` function. In this way, as your *auth.js* will have to import the module, you will be able to mock the module using [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) capabilities.